# handlebars.js Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'call'

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js, handlebars.js

Anyone help with a problem with handlebars.js?

I'm precompiling the templates using handlesbars running on Centos 6.4. To install this I installed:

1. npm: yum -y --enablerepo=epel install npm
2. inherits first to avoid an issue: npm install -g inherits
3. then handlebars itself: npm install -g handlebars

This gives the following versions:

- handlebars@2.0.0-alpha.1 /usr/lib/node_modules/handlebars
- optimist@0.3.7 (wordwrap@0.0.2)
- uglify-js@2.3.6 (async@0.2.10, source-map@0.1.31)

I'm using requirejs to load the following with the app:

- jQuery v1.11.0
- Underscore.js 1.6.0
- handlebars v1.3.0 (with amd)
- backbone.js 1.1.0

Does anyone have a set of version numbers that work together?

Thanks!

Comment: Most probably the problem is with handlebars version, try switching to  different version on handlerbars.

Comment: Thanks Mahesh I found a similar issue on Github and down graded the server side handlebars to v1.3. I've edited the question to show the answer.

Comment: @MarkTDev Rather than putting the answer in the question, please answer your own question and mark it as accepted.

Comment: @Andrew - I will as soon as it lets me. With less than 10 points you have to wait 8 hours before you can answer your own question. I'm a noob...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It was the version of handlebars on the server. NPM installs the latest by default and the version 2 alpha was causing the issue. Found this fix on Github (https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/issues/734):

1. npm uninstall handlebars -g
2. npm install handlebars@1.3 -g

Seems to work fine now, back to work!

(Thanks Mahesh for the pointer.)

Comment: Thanks man! I spent a day fighting with this. npm should really install the latest stable...
btw you should mark your own answer as accepted =)